# Execute command line from script

Tags: scripting

how do i execute this line from script

```
vc@vc-Fly20:~/VC_scripts$ mipi2$udp.sh 192.168.50.9
```

the full script is

```bash
echo "for day camera type (udp), for pilot camera enter (udp2)"

read $udp

echo "./mipi2$udp.sh 192.168.xxx.xxx"

vc@vc-Fly20:~/VC_scripts$ mipi2$udp.sh 192.168.50.9
```

Comment: It looks like you're including part of the system's prompt in that line. You wouldn't include this in anything you typed. The `$` symbol in the middle of the command `mipi$udp.sh` also looks suspect. Are you sure this is what you've been given?

Comment: Are you following instructions for a mipi camera that's available online? If so could you share the URL please

Comment: It is not available online.

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to believe that's what you've given us is "*the full script*". From what I see there are much easier ways of giving the relevant instruction:

1. For day camera, run

   ```
   ./mipi2udp.sh 192.168.50.9
   ```
2. For pilot camera, run

   ```
   ./mipi2udp2.sh 192.168.50.9
   ```

In both cases make sure that `192.168.50.9` is the correct IP address.

Comment: I already did what you wrote and it works. I want to do it from the script.